# Ember.js: How to filter a model by route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to adopt the completed/archived-route-behavior from this [TodoMVC-Tutorial](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/architecture-examples/emberjs/js/router.js).

I'm using Ember 1.7.0, Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.9 and Handlebars 1.3.0.

I want to get all active users on my index route (`example.com/organization/users`) and all archived users on my archived route (`example.com/organization/users/archived`).

But the filter doesn't work: archived users are shown on my index route and vice versa, but my `console.log` output is correct.

**Update:** Please check this JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/puxeludeviga/3/

---

That's how I tried it:

```
Docket.OrganizationUsersRoute = Docket.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({

  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('user');
  },

  renderTemplate: function() {

    // render all posts
    this.render('organization/users', {
      into: 'application'
    });

    // render toolbar
    this.render('organization/toolbar', {
      into: 'application',
      outlet: 'toolbar'
    });
  }

});

Docket.OrganizationUsersIndexRoute = Docket.OrganizationUsersRoute.extend({
  model: function() {
    console.log('index');
    return this.store.filter('user', function(user) {
      return !user.get('archived');
    });
  }
});

Docket.OrganizationUsersArchivedRoute = Docket.OrganizationUsersRoute.extend({
  model: function() {
    console.log('archived');
    return this.store.filter('user', function(user) {
      return user.get('archived');
    });
  }
});
```

And that's my template:

```
<ul class="entries">
    {{#each}}
        <li>
            <div class="actions">
                <button {{action "remove" this}} class="ei-icon-close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="link" {{action "edit" this}} data-uk-modal="{target:'#user-modal'}">
                <span class="before">{{initial}}</span>{{name}}
            </div>
        </li>
    {{else}}
        <li>No users</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

My (shortened) `router.js` file:

```
Docket.Router.map(function() {

  // organization route
  this.resource('organization', function() {

    // user routes
    this.resource('organization.users', { path: '/users' }, function() {
      this.route('archived');
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: Are you sure the archived values are returning what you think they are? ie. If you log the value of archived for each user, is it true/false when it should be?

Comment: Yes, I added `return this.store.filter('user', function(user) { console.log(user.get('name'), user.get('archived')); });` to both routes and it returns the correct results.

Comment: could you please show your `router.js` file

Comment: @slevin At this point, I'd suggest making a JSBin (in general, a JSBin does wonders for revealing your problem to others). I'm having to make too many assumptions about your application. How you are going back in forth between the routes. Link-to helpers? Or do you have render actions. Or are you using the URL. Does it happen in one case and not the others? Etc...you get my point

Comment: OK, I added a link to a JSBin in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found your issue. The thing here is that template you're rendering the users into, has this name:

```
organization/users
```

and turns out that it matches to you organization.users route, so, it is always rendering the data from that route. You need to change the name of you template, let's say to:

```
organization/users_list
```

and then, use that in your routes, it will not have any problems because the name is different to the users route.

something like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="organization/users_list">
  <div class="top">
    <h1>Users</h1>
    {{#link-to 'organization.users.index' class="button-archive"}}active{{/link-to}} - {{#link-to 'organization.users.archived' class="button-archive"}}archived{{/link-to}}
  </div>

  <ul class="entries">
    {{#each}}
      <li>{{name}} - Archived: {{archived}}</li>
    {{else}}
      <li>No users to show</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

and in your routes:

```
renderTemplate: function() {

  // render all posts
  this.render('organization/users_list', {
    into: 'application'
  });

  // render toolbar
  this.render('organization/toolbar', {
    into: 'application',
    outlet: 'toolbar'
  });
}
```